# Chrome does not display full URL

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome (v61 now) displays the full URL in the address bar if it is https, but fails to display the full URL if it is http.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you mean not displaying http:// before the URL, then there is likely no fix. If you are having another issue, you may wish to link to a screenshot or describe the issue in more detail.

Comment: Yes, cutting off the front of the URL. Any idea if there is a configuration option to reinstate the correct behaviour?

Comment: I won't say there isn't definitively, but to the best of my knowledge, the previous fixes for this behavior no longer work. As I understand it, Chrome intends to eventually mark all http pages as "non-secure" and this presentation decision seems to be intended to help highlight https over non-https pages.

Comment: Flagging as not secure makes sense, but displaying an incorrect URL has no logic at all. Other browsers have options to suppress such presentation choices.

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible for Chrome 69+:

> `chrome://flags` > Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL Scheme and Trivial Subdomains > Disabled

Comment: This is split into 3 settings now. For flags-search a "Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL" will match all three of them.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in Chrome 79, all the "Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL" flags have been removed

Comment: Upvote for @Nicolas, downvote for Chrome.

Comment: @Nicolas a [fix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1061576) is now in the pipeline at last.

Comment: @meuh almost 4 years later, never went in

Answer (score 6):

As of Chrome 83, there is a flag for enabling a new context menu option "Show full URLs". *chrome://flags/#omnibox-context-menu-show-full-urls*

Edit: and as of v85, it seems to be enabled for all, so just use the context menu option.

Comment: implemented here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1061576

Comment: as of chrome 120, it's gone

Comment: @JoshHibschman The chrome://flags may have gone, but the menu item "Always show full urls" is still there (right click in omnibox) and works.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: The right answer is now [Madis Otenurm](https://superuser.com/a/1552130/167207)'s.

-> right-click the menu bar and select "Always show full URL"

I believe the fastest way now to show the complete URL of a website is using a keyboard shortcut to give focus to the "omnibar" :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>F6</kbd>

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: There are indeed workarounds using copy / paste or highlighting the URL, but it would be so much better if Chrome displayed the URL correctly in the first place. Other browsers get it right ...

Comment: Yes it is highly unfortunate, I agree.

Comment: Finally the Chrome product managers have listened - just go in the menu to **View** and toggle **Always show full URL**   

Comment: Back here in 2024, ctrl+L or cmd+L seems to be the only option left, all right-clicks and flags are gone

Comment: @DanielW. there it is! submit as an answer so we can upvote ya